# Entity Framework Core - Get DbContext data model

Tags: entity-framework

I need to know information about entities, tables, mappings, keys etc for the given instance of `DbContext`. In Entity Framework 6 I was writing `edmx` like this:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(dbContext, xmlWriter);
```

which I then used to build my own data model (this is needed for a tool which supports loading data from different sources). How do I get such information for the new `EF Core` (previous `EF 7`)? I could use `Reflection`, but this will give me only the `conceptual schema`, while I also need `mappings and storage schema`. I've been looking through the `EF` source code for a while now, but don't seem to find any object, that stores all the required data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    var entityType = ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof (Entity_Basic));
    var tableName = entityType.SqlServer().TableName;
    var columnName = entityType.GetProperties().ToList()[0].SqlServer().ColumnName;
}
```